# vuejs v-for execution difference with or withouth sub-components

Tags: vue.js

consider you got a list of objects you want to iterate over of which each object contains an array with the name `f`. Also you got a log function that prints a string from a parameter and returns true. Here you see the corresponding template section:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div v-for="o in objArr" v-if="log('base')">
            <div v-for="a in o.f" v-if="log('subbase')">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Here is an example of the data if have used:

```
objArr: [
    { a : 1, b : 2, c : 3, d : 4, e : 5, f : [10,9,8]},
    { a : 1, b : 2, c : 3, d : 4, e : 5, f : [10,9,8]},
],
```

Now I change a random array element in one of the Objects. I do this on the console with:
`$vm.objArr[3].f.splice(2,1,4);`
(This will change the 4th Object, and within that object replace the 3rd array element with the value of 4).

Because of vue's reactive capabilities, it will detect the change and rerender the necessary components. Imagine the objArr has 2 elements and the array of object we are changing has 3 elements. The Output will be:

```
base
subbase
subbase
subbase

base
subbase
subbase
subbase
```

Now I want to use components as wrappers. I change above to:

```
<div>
    <div >
        <performance-test v-for="o in objArr" v-if="log('base')" :mydata="o">
        </performance-test>
    </div>
</div>
```

And inside the performance-test component we got:

```
<div>
    <div v-for="a in mydata.f" v-if="log('basesub')">
    </div>
</div>
```

We still got a for-loop inside a for-loop and I use the same method as above to change the `base` components array, but vue decides to update different this time. The output is:

```
subbase
subbase
subbase
```

I can't make up my mind right now. If I don't want to have any data (and logic) in my subcomponents. How would I prevent vue from going all over the whole object even if only one array inside a single object changed?

Hope you can help.

Comment: sorry, updated with a data example like I have used.

Comment: have you tried to use `:key` with a unique value/id in `v-for` elements?

Comment: I just tried: for the first example it makes no difference. @acdcjunior posted an example, but I see no difference either for the first method.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem is you have not declared a `:key` when using `performance-test` (a custom component) in a `v-for`. Try:

```html
<performance-test v-for="o in objArr" v-if="log('base')" :mydata="o" :key="o.a">
</performance-test>
```

Note: `o.a` must be unique for each `o`!

[**Codesandbox working demo here**](https://codesandbox.io/s/3z2yyk441).

Comment: In your code vue still has to update the whole DOM, when updating f inside an object of objArray: the output is still 4x(base 3x subbase). Though I cannot figure out why when using subcomponents, the output is 4x(222base) before printing 3x(222basesub)